# How to create a vector of labels from a numerical vector?

Tags: r

My question is simple but i failed to find a straightforward solution :

Suppose that i have a numerical vector , for example :

```
x=c(1,1,1,2,3,2,3,3)
```

If we consider that `1` represents the first cluster denoted as `"cluster1"` , `2` the cluster 1 denoted as `"cluster1"` etc : how can i obtain the following output :

```
y=c("cluster1","cluster1","cluster1","cluster2","cluster3","cluster2","cluster3","cluster3")
```

I whish my question is clear.

Thank you for help in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to answer comments:

```
clust.names <- c("setosa", "versicolor",  "virginica" )
x=c(1,1,1,2,3,2,3,3) 
y <- clust.names[x]
y
# [1] "setosa"     "setosa"     "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"  "versicolor" "virginica" 
# [8] "virginica"
```

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm wanting to transform numerical indices to iris$species levels.

Comment: 1 represents "setosa"    , 2   represents "versicolor" , 3  represents  "virginica" .